# The stored procedure call with cursors throws invalid column name exception

Tags: oracle, hibernate, cursors, spring-boot-jpa

We have a Spring Boot application where we need to connect to Oracle DB and fetch data via stored procedures. Each of our stored procedure has `REF_CURSOR` as OUT parameters. I am trying the same using `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` and `@Entity` annotations. We are using `ojdbc14.jar` in `pom.xml` and `Oracle12cDialect` in `application.properties` file. I get the exception **Invalid Column Name** while executing my piece of code. Also in the entity class I had to introduce a field with annotation `@Id`, although there is no such field being returned by the `REF_CURSOR` of my stored procedure. Can this be a problem? Also not defining `@Id` field is not an option since Hibernate throws an exception then. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Implementation and Problem is very similar to the question
[Invalid column name exception when calling an Oracle stored procedure with ref_cursor through JPA 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752658/invalid-column-name-exception-when-calling-an-oracle-stored-procedure-with-ref-c)

But no answer is posted there

Comment: You need to include the code you're executing (and related things, like your entity classes) if you want us to tell you why it's throwing an exception.

Comment: Actually that is against the company policy, so I cant post the code. But please let me know if you would like to see any specific pieces of code. I can then post some demo implementation.

Comment: Implementation & Problem are very similar to the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752658/invalid-column-name-exception-when-calling-an-oracle-stored-procedure-with-ref-c

Comment: @LearningJava It would be nice to see a contract of your stored procedure (some simplified version that shows important/problematic part) and appropriate entity part.

Comment: @StemK - procedure proc_name (p_in_param1 in nvarcharr2, p_out_list out sys_refcursor). Hope this contract helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simple example how you can achieve it:

1. The database schema.

```sql
create table MY_PATIENT
(
   PAT_RECID  number,
   PAT_NAME varchar2(100),
   
   constraint PAT_PK primary key(PAT_RECID)
);

create table MY_ORDER
(
   ORD_RECID  number,
   ORD_CODE varchar2(15),
   ORD_PATID number,
   
   constraint ORD_PK primary key(ORD_RECID),
   constraint ORD_PAT_FK foreign key(ORD_PATID) references MY_PATIENT(PAT_RECID),
   constraint ORD_CODE_UNIQUE unique (ORD_CODE)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fetch_patient_orders(
  patientId IN NUMBER, 
  patientOrders OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN patientOrders FOR
   SELECT *
   FROM MY_ORDER
   WHERE ORD_PATID = patientId;
END;
```

2. The entity definition.

```java
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(
   @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
      name = "fetch_patient_orders",
      procedureName = "fetch_patient_orders",
      resultClasses = Order.class, 
      parameters = {
         @StoredProcedureParameter(
            name = "patientId",
            type = Long.class,
            mode = ParameterMode.IN
         ),
         @StoredProcedureParameter(
            name = "patientOrders",
            type = Class.class,
            mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR
         )
      }
   )
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ORDER")
public class Order
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ORD_RECID")
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "ORD_CODE")
   private String code;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "ORD_PATID")
   private Patient patient;
}
```

2. And usage:

```java
List<Order> orders = session.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("fetch_patient_orders")
    .setParameter("patientId", 2L)
    .getResultList();
```

It was tested with hibernate 5.4.12.Final, `ojdbc8.jar`, `Oracle12cDialect`.
See also the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp-named-query).

The described above approach will work in a pure hibernate application, but not in spring boot app.

According to the spring boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data-properties):

> **Connection to a Production Database**
>
> Production database connections can also be auto-configured by using a pooling `DataSource`. Spring Boot uses the following algorithm for choosing a specific implementation:
>
> 1. We prefer [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for its performance and concurrency. If HikariCP is available, we always choose it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the Tomcat pooling DataSource is available, we use it.
> 3. If neither HikariCP nor the Tomcat pooling datasource are available and if [Commons DBCP2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) is available, we use it.
>
> If you use the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` or `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` “starters”, you automatically get a dependency to HikariCP.
>
> You can bypass that algorithm completely and specify the connection pool to use by setting the `spring.datasource.type` property.

So, spring boot uses HikariCP JDBC connection pool by default. And it looks like it has a problem with `REF_CURSOR` parameter registering:

```
o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Registering statement [HikariProxyCallableStatement@770201936 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper@528a6369]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [patientId] as [BIGINT] - [2]
o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.cursor.spi.RefCursorSupport]
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error registering REF_CURSOR parameter [patientOrders] [n/a]
```

When I use the oracle specific data source pool in the `application.properties`:

```
# com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource (default value)
spring.datasource.type=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

all work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately mine is a Spring Boot app