# Hibernate is resolving the REFCURSOR return type to null, throwing Invalid column type: 2012

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying an example given https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/129bc15d0ccc459610c2 , but failing to register REFCURSOR.

I'm trying to call a stored procedure having only one out parameter which is a refcursor using spring data jpa.

I'm using:

```
OJDBC8
Hibernate 5
Spring Boot 2
JDK 8
Oracle 12.2.0.1.0
```

Even though the example provided in the above link is using EclipseLink, I assume the approach is same.

My Entity is defined as

```java
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ 
   @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
      name = "findPersons",
      procedureName = "FIND_PERSONS",
      resultClasses = Person.class,
      parameters = { 
          @StoredProcedureParameter(
             name = "P_RETURN",
             mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR,
             type = void.class) 
      }
   ) 
})
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

and repository as

```java
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Serializable> {

    @Procedure
    List<Person> findPersons();
}
```

Some times I see invalid column type :2012 and some times null. I could not understand what the issue is.

I tried to see If I can set the type as `OracleTypes.CUROSOR`, but `StoredProcedureParameter` takes a class not an int.

I also tried

```java
@StoredProcedureParameter(
   name = "P_RETURN",
   mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR,
   type = Class.class
)
```

but no luck. Any direction here?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and making it more readable . But is there any suggestion for me here on how to resolve it. It seems there were several questions in stackoverflow on the same problem with same example provided in the link and none had  a solution

Comment: After a more debug into Hibernate library and some reading on this problem, it seems it is all coming down to the mismatch between Hibernate using Types.REF_CURSOR (2012) and the conflict with OJDBC 8 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement not able to map 2012 to any internal type.  I'm not sure, if there is any way to override this behavior and pass in a Hibernate type compatible  with OJDBC 8 version.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61030638/6277104) will be helpful.